# Generate random 2D matrix with unique rows in octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to generate a 2D matrix(1000x3) with random values in the range of 1 to 10 in octave. Using randi(10,1000,3) will generate a matrix with repeated row values. But I want to generate unique(unrepeated) rows. Is there any way that, I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily by getting the cartesian product to create all possibilities and shuffle the array as follows. To create the cartesian product, you will need my custom [cartprod.m function](http://pastebin.com/SsdfYiUe) that generates a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

```
C = cartprod(1:10,1:10,1:10);
```

The following line then shuffles the cartesian product `C`.

```
S = C(randperm( size(C,1) ),:);
```

Notes:

- Every row in `S` is unique and you can verify that `size( unique( S ) ) == 1000`.
- I should note that this code works on Matlab 2015a. I haven't tested it in Octave, which is what OP seems to be using. I've been told the syntax is pretty much identical though.

Comment: I want to work on the same matrix(1000x3). As I am using randperm, the rows are changing each time. Is there any way that, I will just once generate that matrix and then work on it?

Comment: @Cherry Awesome :) Well it's all stored into a variable S right, so once it's in memory, just work on that? If you want to store the randomness, you can also store it like this `R = randperm( size(C,1) );` and replace the code I had above with `R`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Cherry Also since I don't have Octave, can you let me know if my custom `cartprod` function actually works there too? If so, I will use it for future Octave answers too for others!

Comment: your cartprod function works fine in Octave. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @Cherry Sweet! Anytime :D

Answer (score 2):

You can generate all possible three-item sequences drawn from 1 through 10, with replacement, using the following function:

```
function result = nchoosek_replacement(n, k)

    %// Edge cases: just return an empty matrix 
    if k < 1 || n < 1 || k >= n
        result = [];
        return
    end

    reps = n^(k-1);
    result = zeros(n^k, k);
    cur_col = repmat(1:n, reps, 1);
    result(:,1) = cur_col(:);

    %// Base case: when k is 1, just return the
    %// fully populated matrix 'result'
    if k == 1
        return
    end

    %// Recursively generate a matrix that will
    %// be used to populate columns 2:end
    next = nchoosek_replacement(n, k-1);

    %// Repeatedly use the matrix above to
    %// populate the matrix 'result'
    for i = 1:n
        cur_range = (i-1)*reps+1:i*reps;
        result(cur_range, 2:end) = next;
    end

end
```

With this function defined, you can now generate all possible sequences. In this case there are exactly 1000 so they could simply be shuffled with `randperm`. A more general approach is to sample from them with `randsample`, which would also allow for smaller matrices if desired:

```
max_value = 10;
row_size = 3;    
num_rows = 1000;

possible = nchoosek_replacement(max_value, row_size);
indices = randsample(size(possible, 1), num_rows);
data = possible(indices, :);
```

Comment: `Error: File: nchoosek_replacement.m Line: 11 Column: 16
()-indexing must appear last in an index expression. `

Comment: Even after fixing this issue and any subsequent ones, it's not as concise or logical as my answer. Also you didn't have to delete your answer, I would have undownvoted if you edited your answer :)

Comment: I ran it in Matlab 2015a. I've never seen something like this work `repmat(1:n, reps, 1)(:)` you can't select all elements after a function call, otherwise I'd have much less code in my codebase :P

Comment: Oh. OP is working in octave where this works fine (at least for me) but I'll make it more general.